# PhpStorm Structural Search

Tags: php, html, intellij-idea, phpstorm, structural-search

I have a bunch of `li` tags in PHP Blade templates that I want to convert to `div` tags and change the class name. Search/Replace would be an easy solution but it will only change the opening tag, not the closing tag.
Regex can be dangerous to search/replace over an entire project.
So I found out about Structural Search Replace which sounds exactly what I need but can't understand how it works.

Search Template:

```html
<li class="navi-item">
    $content$
</li>
```

Replace Template:

```html
<div class="menu-item">
    $content$
</div>
```

Do the search in my `views/` directory where all my `.blade.php` view files are (changing "File Type" to PHP), but it comes up empty.

Comment: *"changing "File Type" to PHP"* This might be an issue. You see, `.blade.php` files are NOT PHP but a special Blade file type and the main templating language (after the actual Blade) is HTML. But HTML does not seem to work as well (for me). It works fine if a file extension is `.html` (and treated as HTML File by the IDE of course)... but it ignores `.blade.php`

Comment: A suggestion to try based on the above: 1) Change the file association at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types` -- just add `*.blade.php` pattern to HTML File (it will ask to remove from Blade, do it). 2) Do your changes (if they work; they should do) 3) When done -- change the file association back. Not ideal but worth checking out.

Comment: P.S. And if it will work -- please file a ticket at PhpStorm Issue Tracker so there would be a Blade context as well (or they can make it work for HTML in Blade files as well): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

Comment: P.P.S. Found a similar ticket for Smarty. Funny thing that it says it works for Blade there.... https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-50380

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne , I had tried 'html' but it was of course, ignoring the blade.php files. I changed Blade file type to something temporary (*.bladez.php) and added *.blade.php to HTML and ran the exact same search above and it worked. Please add your answer and I'll accept it as the correct one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (changing "File Type" to PHP), but it comes up empty.

This must be the issue. You see, despite the `.php` extension, the `.blade.php` files are NOT PHP but a special Blade file type and the main underlying templating language (after the actual Blade) is HTML. Sadly using the HTML option on SSR does not seem to work as well in my tests. But it works fine if a file extension is actually `.html` (and treated as "HTML file'' by the IDE of course)...

Possible workaround based on the above:

1. Change the file association at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types`; just add `*.blade.php` pattern to HTML File (it will ask to remove from Blade, do it).
2. Do your searches/make replacements (it should work OK).
3. When all is done: change the file association back.

Not ideal by any means (as it requires playing with file associations that is inconvenient to do if you need a quick simple search) but at least it works.

---

**P.S.** Found a similar ticket for Smarty. Funny thing is that it says it works for Blade there... https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-50380